# Create SubSet of a dataSet ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a dataset which is having some 28 columns Now I want to make another dataSet that will contain two dataTable having 14 columns in each table from the previous dataset.

Help needed.

Comment: a dataset does not have columns.  Does the table with the 28 columns has any data?

Comment: Does the datatable has any data?

Comment: By the way you can edit your question to make it more clear, plus you probably will earn abadge for it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will asumme you have some data in it.

Create to Datatables one with the first 14 columns(firstPart), and the other with the lasts 14 columns plus the primary key(secondPart).

```
    DataTable firstPart = new DataTable();
    //Initialize columns here...

    DataTable secondPart = new DataTable();
    //Initialize columns here...

    foreach(DataRow r in original.Rows){
        DataRow f = firstPart.NewRow();
        f[0] = r[0];
        f[1] = r[1];
        f[2] = r[2];
        f[3] = r[3];
        f[4] = r[4];
        f[5] = r[5];
        f[6] = r[6];
        f[7] = r[7];
        f[8] = r[8];
        f[9] = r[9];
        f[10] = r[10];
        f[11] = r[11];
        f[12] = r[12];
        f[13] = r[13];
        firtPart.Rows.Add(f);

        DataRow s = secondPart.NewRow();
        s[0] = r[0];
        s[1] = r[14];
        s[2] = r[15];
        s[3] = r[16];
        s[4] = r[17];
        s[5] = r[18];
        s[6] = r[19];
        s[7] = r[20];
        s[8] = r[21];
        s[9] = r[22];
        s[10] = r[23];
        s[11] = r[24];
        s[12] = r[25];
        s[13] = r[26];
        s[14] = r[27];
        secondPart.Rows.Add(f);
    }
    firtPart.AcceptChanges();
    secondPart.AcceptChanges();
```

You may add constrints to the the tables collection and/or relationships between tables in the dataset's realtionships collection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [DataView.ToTable Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx) if you would like to do it without a `loop`. It creates a subset from a datatable, by defining required column names

```
   dtLogExport == dsManifestAuditTrailLog.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable(false, "RevisionNo", "TabName", "RecordNumber")
```